# Mongoose updateAttributes (set + save) to have more functional writing?

Tags: mongoose

In active record, there is [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) which allows a more functional writing.

Instead of:

```
Model.findOne({criteria: 'foo'}).then(model => {
  model.criteria = 'bar'; 
  model.save();
});
```

Writing:

```
Model.findOne({criteria: 'foo'}).then(model => model.updateAttributes({criteria: 'bar'}));
```

Ain't there a similar way to achieve this in Mongoose?

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: Oups correct, I forgot to write it down. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do `doc.set({ criteria: 'bar' }).save()`.

You could also define a method in your schema

```
Schema.methods.updateAttributes = function (object) {
    return this.set(object).save()
};
```

in order to do

```
Model.findOne({ criteria: 'foo' }).then(doc => doc.updateAttributes({ criteria: 'bar' }));
```

And if you want to re-use this method, you can [create a plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html).